# SSIS - Custom message into logs

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am in process of researching the best way to track all the queries which run within an SSIS package. The plan is to create an automatised report which could pull from SQL server that shows the queries the SSIS package runs and where it loads the data. I was wondering is it possible to customised a log message. My plan would be to insert a log after the task has run and say the logic which ran.

An example would be if I had a Execute SQL task I could write a custom message that would say the logic which just ran. I have been trying a various of other solutions but couldn't really see much which would help me create a directory of the info of all SSIS packages.

Comment: What do you mean by the "logic" which just ran? Like for example if it is an INSERT statement you want to mention in which table you inserted the data and from where the data is coming ?

Comment: Yes , Lets say I have a SSIS package and within it and might have a truncate statement or a execute store procedure  statement. Is it possible to extract that info within SQL to say which statements are running in each package. From my research you can name the tasks similar to what your running but is there an easier way of doing it instead of updating all packages. A further question i would have ,is it possible to then even see the logic within the data flow so you know what logic is being used the extract the source data. It doesnt seem to be stored in any SQL table from what i could see.

Comment: You can't. Of course you can add comments to queries in scripts tasks, but normally that's only a subset of all database interaction taking place. Adding an application name to the connection string(s) will give a rough indication.